# scroll to element with jquery

Tags: jquery, scroll

There is the scrollTop method in jquery but I want a scrollBottom method.

My use case is that the user clicks on the top right corner on an element and somewhere deep down the website there is the element #test I want to do a scroll to bottom so the user can see this element.

How would you do that? I know there is a jquery scrollTo plugin is it recommened to use? Such a simple task?...

UPDATE

I have updated my question with a code sample which is taken partly from the above 'jquery scroll to element' dupe vote:

```
var container = $('#view');
var scrollTo = $('#test');

container.animate({
    scrollTop: scrollTo.offset().top - container.offset().top + container.scrollTop()
});
```

These are the values I get from debugging and the scroll bottom does not work, the screen stands still nothing moves.

```
scrollTo.offset().top => 0
container.offset().top => 274.75
container.scrollTop() => 0
```

My element row1 is so I guess at top 1500px but probably the problem is it has no top value... How can I solve that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery scroll To Element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I've understood from your question is, you want to scroll to the bottom of the page, so you could use this:

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height()-$(window).height() });
```

if you want to scroll to particular ID the you can use this:

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#myID").scrollTop() }, 1000);
```

Comment: Then you understood it wrongly. I want to scroll to an element which is in direction bottom of the page. At least I want to scroll down and not scrollTop.

Comment: @Pascal then check second line of code... this will take you to top of that div

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
var p = $("#test");
var offset = p.offset();
$("body").scrollTop(offset.top);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
 <body>
        <div style="height:2500px">
            <button class="Top" id="button1" >1</button>
        </div>
            <button class="Link" id="button1" >2</button>
    </body>
```

Script

```
$('.Top').click(function () {
   $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()}, 'slow');
   return false;
   });

   $('.Link').click(function () {
   $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
   return false;
   });
```

Follow this fiddle and see live example

http://jsfiddle.net/Ur3Dv/

Comment: Do not forget to include jquery in your page

Comment: This is not my use case. I do not want to scroll down to the very bottom/the final end because with a height of 2500px you use my button2 could be at top:1000px when I then click on the button1 I do not see button2 because I am too far down at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("your element on which, if user clicks the scrolling shall proceed").click(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");
  return false;
});
```

I hope, this will sort your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

check out my ten lines jQuery plugin (uncompressed). it do what you want and more though it is very simple

https://github.com/Samer-Al-iraqi/Simple-jQuery.scrollTo

As jQuery utility:

`$.scrollTo(to, duration, func);`

OR as extension to jQuery prototype:

`$('selector').scrollTo(duration, func);`

The `to` part in the first form can accept a number of pixels, jQuery selector string, `end` word (to scroll the end of page), an element or jQuery object.

hope it will help somebody.